# Publish a build artifect to a remote Git Repo - Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-repos

I have a build pipeline and I would like to publish the build artifect to a remote location which is a folder in an external Git repo. I have been able to create a "Azure Repos/Team Foundation" Server service connection to point to the external Azure DevOps. how do I consume that service connection through my build pipeline tasks? I could also use a release pipeline and copy the package over to a remote Git repo as well. How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution for this by using this extension - you can use it to point to a

1. TFVC repo
2. Git repo
3. Build pipeline
4. Release pipeline

[TFS Artifects for Release Management](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscs-rm.vss-services-externaltfs&targetId=69338f1f-d726-46b7-9ec7-0082f0e61192)

Comment: @AzureNinja can you provide more details of what you did? I want to push my dlls to a heroku git repo